# Python PostgreSQL parameterized WHERE IN clause

Tags: python, postgresql

I have 2 different databases and those are not linked. I need to filter the data from database B using values from database A.

So here is my table
Database A, table filter_data

```
| Filter    | Value    |
| Commodity | CPU      |
| Commodity | GPU      |
```

Database B, table forecast_data

```
| Commodity | Value    |
| CPU       | 100      |
| GPU       | 200      |
| HDD       | 300      |
| SSD       | 400      |
```

So what I wanted to achieve is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM forecast_data WHERE Commodity IN (SELECT Value FROM filter_data)
```

But since these are in different database and not possible to link, I need to "export" the commodity list from database A, form SQL statement and then execute it in database B.
So above query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM forecast_data WHERE Commodity IN (%s)
```

But putting the exported data from database A may expose to SQL injection

My Python code, using psycopg2:

```
def select_command_postgres_no_argument(conn, sql):
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql)
        return cur.fetchall()

def select_command_postgres_with_argument(conn, sql, sql_args = ()):
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, sql_args)
        return cur.fetchall()

# Retrieve the list of commodities
commodity_records = select_command_postgres_no_argument(postgres_conn, "SELECT Value FROM filter_data")
commodity = []
for row in commodity_records:
    commodity.append(row[0])
commodity_text = ', '.join(f"'{w}'" for w in commodity)

src_sql = "SELECT * FROM forecast_data WHERE Commodity IN (%s)" % (commodity_text)
```

I'm afraid this may cause SQL injection

```
src_sql = "SELECT * FROM forecast_data WHERE Commodity IN (%s)" % (commodity_text)
```

How to replace this in a safe way?

Comment: If you are using psycopg2, you should read the ["Passing parameters to SQL queries"](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) section of the manual. If you are *not* using psycopg2, you should tell us what you are using. (And notice that the right argument to the `%` operator — which you are right that you should not be using in the first place — should always be a tuple of values, to avoid headaches when the value itself is a tuple.)

Comment: @TurePålsson I'm using psycopg2. Do you mean I should use `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = ANY(%s);", (ids,))` and it is safe from SQL injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using psycopg2, you should use [its mechanism for passing parameters to queries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries); that will take care of any necessary quoting for you. Any other DB library worth its salt should have a similar mechanism.

(In this  case, you can either use the `=ANY` construct with a list, or convert to a tuple and use `IN`.)